# Trigger event on change of query parameter in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Is there is any way to trigger an action when a query string added to the URL or the query string changes using javascript or jQuery

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+url+query+change+event+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** .

It took me less time to find the dupes than for you to write the question. Could you not have done that investigation yourself?

Comment: the duplicate questions are about URL Hash change, the above question is about query param change

Comment: Nope there are answers in all of them and the 2nd AND 3rd are about querystring NOT hashchange as the title says